# Recover Ubuntuone files after 14.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu-one

I need to restore my documents and folders, since the installation of 14.04 reformatted my harddisk.

I can sign in to Ubuntuone, but I see no way to make it restore the files to my harddisk.

Comment: Ubuntu files has been removed from ubuntu installation and it was anounced it will close (they even send mails quoting this ubuntuone users)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu One has been removed from 14.04. You will no longer be able to get the app, using Software Center.

However, You might like to access/restore your data using (at least) following ways.

1. You may download all your data directly from https://files.one.ubuntu.com/download.zip as zipped file [Easiest way! [Thanks to dobey]](https://askubuntu.com/a/458573/174260)
2. [Install UbuntuOne client](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/) on on other OSes (Like Windows, Android) and sync.
3. Use a live cd of an older version of Ubuntu and Install UbuntuOne (I haven't tested but it should work)
4. [Access you file via FTP](http://bit.ly/1jb3ck1). It is easy to setup (and I did this right now).

[Follow this Video](http://bit.ly/1jPiXyT). However, there is a small change in the connection setup. While trying to setup FTP server, use this address

`ftp://127.0.0.1:2121`

and hit 'Connect'. Everything else should be remain same as tutorial and video.

After connecting to UbuntuOne you will see your files in a directory named "Ubuntu One". Copy the entire directory to your local drive.

***REMEMBER, It’s Time to say [goodbye to Ubuntu One file services](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/).***

Comment: The Android client does not do "sync." It only allows download of individual files, the same as accessing your files via the web site.

Comment: How to extract the '.sigtar' file?

Answer (score 2):

You can [download your files as a zip](https://files.one.ubuntu.com/download.zip) on the Ubuntu One web site now.