# How to download all files from Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and Ubuntu One isn't installed by default and their download page says it comes pre installed, which doesn't help with anything.

I wanna move all my files from Ubuntu One to Dropbox, but downloading one file at a time from the browser and upload it again to dropbox will take way too long.

Is there any way to get Ubuntu One on Ubuntu 14.04? or somehow download all files from the Ubuntu One website?

I see they updated their site:
[image]

Comment: What says `sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client`?

Comment: updated question with output

Comment: i am still running ubuntuone-client under 14.04 cause i have upgraded from 13.10. I think you should have do the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover Ubuntuone files after 14.04 installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449395/recover-ubuntuone-files-after-14-04-installation)

Comment: I see this is a duplicate, but I ran into another problem, I have a folder named "Skjøl" and within that a folder called "Skúli" and I can't access it from FTP, does anyone have a fix for that? I can't rename the folder in one.ubuntu.com :( - http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202014-04-22%2016:32:40.png

Comment: Is it possible to download the U1 files via rsync? The bandwidth I'm getting is dreadfully slow.

Answer (score 4):

Follow [this guide](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-can-access-my-files-via-ftp-on-ubuntu/) to connect via FTP, then copy and paste from the new window to your home directory. Here are the steps:

1. In a terminal:

   ```
   mkdir ~/u1ftp
   cd ~/u1ftp
   wget https://launchpad.net/u1ftp/trunk/0.1/+download/u1ftp-0.1.zip
   ln -s ~/u1ftp/u1ftp-0.1.zip u1ftp
   python u1ftp
   ```

   **Leave the terminal open**
2. Open a file browser and click `File > Connect to Server...` and enter the following:

   ```
   Server address: ftp://`localhost`:2121
   Ubuntu One username (email address) and password
   ```
3. Wait a moment and your folder pops into view. Copy items from it.

In my experience I encountered several permission errors. I clicked *skip-all* and expect I'll be missing some items, but they were not critical to me. YMMV.

Comment: It would be much better if you included the major points of the article here and provide the link for reference. Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Every filename with an accented character throws permission errors, which is a wrong error message BTW. For these files, you can always manually download them from the U1 webpage.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an option to download all your files as a zip file, directly from [the Ubuntu One website](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard/) .

Comment: I tried today, but the download is abruptly interrupted after 155 MB or so. Retried several times, I think around 10, with 2 browsers and SteadyFlow download manager. No luck at all.