# How do I download from my ubuntu-one account now?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 14.04

I have my files synced with ubuntu-one. But as the service will be closed, I need to download the files. I installed 14.04 and my previous documents were deleted.In 14.04 , there is no ubuntu-1 app, so I can't really do anything. what should I do to download the files. In the site I see only the message I don't see any option to download, everywhere its the same message `The service has been discontinued` . no download options.

Here is a screenshot after I use the files (https://one.ubuntu.com/files/) link:

[image]

Comment: The package ubuntuone-client and a bunch of other ubuntu one related packages are still in the trusty archive. Had the impression that it would work as usual a couple of more months for those who already had an account, but maybe I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just login via the web interface at http://one.ubuntu.com/ and download your files to your computer. After that you can sync them to another cloud.

Comment: I don't see any option to download, everywhere its the same message `The service has been discontinued`

Comment: I have successfully logged into my account and can view all my files. Complete shutdown is not till 1st June so you should be able to view and download your files as of now. Can you post a screenshot of the webpage?

Comment: http://pbrd.co/1nLUMCt here is the link after I clicked files in the bottom left.

Comment: https://one.ubuntu.com/files/ redirects you to that page?

Comment: yup , I have found that, it was my other email ID, but still..,, will I have to download each files?? :o .. I have got thousands of files. Is there any option to download the whole folder?

Comment: You can look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449395/recover-ubuntuone-files-after-14-04-installation) for options on how to do that.